# Java why are "readAllBytes" and "readNBytes" methods not synchronized?

Tags: java, io, stream

I often see these methods as not synchronized in `InputStream` hierarchy in Java 9. And want to know what if when multiple threads run these methods ? For instance, `read(byte b[], int off, int len)` and `readNbytes` methods are almost the same but `readNBytes` not synchronized. Why ?

Comment: Whether a method is `synchronized`, is an implementation detail. So when I look at `InputStream` or, e.g. `FileInputStream`, *neither*, `read(byte b[], int off, int len)` nor `readNbytes`, is `synchronized`, so you must be looking at a different input stream implementation when you see `read` being `synchronized`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronization requires more overhead and if not needed would therefore lower performance unnecessarily. Another example pertinent to your question is the difference between `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer`.

If it's possible that your input stream is closed asynchronously, you shouldn't use `readNbytes`.

`readNbytes` is useful to help avoid memory problems with large files. This would make it preferable to `readAllBytes` in those situations because it allows you to easily read a file (or part of a file) in manageable chunks of up to N bytes.

Comment: So do you know when should I use it ?

Comment: But `readNBytes` method uses `read` method. and so how is it more faster ?

Comment: I don’t see, how the difference between `readNbytes` and `readAllBytes` is related to the question.